# Composition of iPhone Accelerometer Values

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, accelerometer

I am receiving accelerometer values with an update interval of 1 second, using the startAccelerometerUpdates() method of CMMotionManager. Does anyone know if the values I get back are the actual values of the time the update takes place or sth. like a mean/min/max value of the time within the update interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the values you see are instantaneous values.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager

Comment: Thanks, i searched for such a keyword. I also looked for it within the documentation but at more detailed places like here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_raw_accelerometer_events and at this point, there isnt any clear statement anymore.